# Complex matrix proof given characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_{n×n}{(\mathbb{C}})$ be a matrix with characteristic polynomial $p(x) =cx^a \prod^k_{i=1}(\lambda_i−x)$ where $\lambda _i\neq 0$ for all $i$ and $a \in {\mathbb{Z}}_{>0}$.  Show that if $\dim(\ker(A)) +k=n$, then $A=C^2$ for some complex matrix $C$.

Tried writing a using the dimension formula to consider different cases for when the eigenvalues are $0$.

Having trouble relating the characteristic polynomial to prove that $A$ must be a complex matrix squared.

Comment: Do you have access to the Jordan canonical form?  (I.e. every square matrix over the complex numbers can, after a change of basis,  be written in Jordan canonical form)

Comment: All the available information is given in the question.